# Remove a value from 1D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D array and by plotting a histogramm and fitting it by a Gaussian I want to create a signal over noise map (with a sigma scale from my gaussian).
I have the value 0 at several places but I want to keep only the values < 0 and > 0.

Can I write my script like this ?

```
new_SN_map = temp_SN_map[(temp2_SN_map < 0) & (temp_SN_map > 0)]
```

Is there a way to automatically delete the value 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future readers I'll rename your array to make it more general:

```
array = temp_SN_map
```

---

Regarding your problem, there are different ways. For starters your proposal would work:

```
new_array = array[(array < 0) & (array > 0)]
```

But there are alternatives:

```
new_array = array[array != 0]        # using only one comparison

import numpy as np
new_array = array[np.nonzero(array)] # using np.nonzero

new_array = array[np.where(array)]   # using np.where
```

- Using `np.nonzero()`<sup>[1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)</sup> is especially tailored for excluding not-zero values.
- Using `np.where()`<sup>[2](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)</sup> or `!= 0` are for excluding a special value.
- Using `(a < 0) & (a > 0)` is good if you want to exclude a certain range.

Notice however that each of those can do everything that the other ones are doing so it depends primary on what you think is most appropriate/readable or if you care about efficiency you need to time it what's fastest.

Comment: I have a question which go further. Assuming that I have a 2D array. Why the 2D array become 1D array when I apply this process ?

Comment: because numpy can only handle 2D arrays with gaps so it **must** convert them to 1D. You could also use `np.mgrid` or `np.ogrid` to keep the coordinate information.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo is your 1D numpy array.

foo[np.where(foo != 0)]
```